# Proof verification for the Squeeze Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Squeeze Theorem:** 
*If $s_n \leq t_n \leq u_n$ for all n and if both $s_n \rightarrow L$ and $u_n \rightarrow L$  then $t_n \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.*

Here is how I did it:

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|s_n -L| \lt \epsilon, |u_n-L| \lt \epsilon$, N corresponds to $\epsilon$. We can rewrite this as $-\epsilon \lt s_n -L \lt \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon \lt u_n-L \lt \epsilon$.

I am going to try to show that $-\epsilon \lt t_n-L \lt \epsilon$

By preservation of the order,

$s_n \leq t_n \leq u_n$

$-\epsilon \lt s_n-L \leq t_n-L \leq u_n-L \lt \epsilon$

Hence, we can see that

$-\epsilon \lt  t_n-L  \lt \epsilon$, or $|t_n -L| \lt \epsilon$.

Thus, $t_n \rightarrow L$ as well.

Comment: Should be $-\epsilon$ on the left sides (you missed minus), but apart from this typo it seems good to me.

Comment: I edited, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Perhaps, I would mention what the $\epsilon$ is, that it is arbitrary small $\epsilon >0$, but that is probably apparent to anyone familiar with limits definitions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have fixed the typos, your proof is fine.